Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Segregated Witness? [Finished]
Segregated Witness (BIP141, BIP 143, BIP 144, BIP145) is about to be released with Bitcoin Core v0.13.1.
Currently, we have 21 questions, and there has been a lot of discussion about SegWit already, but I'm sure that there are more questions to be answered.
Please use segregated-witness to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about benefits, down-sides, implementation details, or whatever else you want to know about it.
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-10-27. Happy posting!

There were five questions asked about Segregated Witness during the challenge with a total of four answers:

Using segwit and creating Pay-To-Witness (P2WPKH) addresses – m1xolyd1an [+2]
How was the 95% miner adoption threshold determined? – 2quick 4u [+2]
How is the transaction's nVersion field changed with segregated witness? – StephenM347 [+2]
How do you tell if witness data has been tampered with? – Nick ODell [+5]
What new peer services do segregated witness nodes need to implement? – Nick ODell [+1]

Thanks for posting!
